# Is there a Python function equivalent for R average tables with contr.sum

Tags: python, r, glm, anova

I a desparately trying to reproduce in python with statsmodel an equivalent to linear regression, anova, and averagetable (adjusted mean) with contr.sum as a contrast to force all my coefficients to sum to zero.

Tried ols from statsmodel, the resulting anova_lm method gave me the same results anova wise as R except that coefficients did not sum to zero.

Then went glm with fit_constrained and a vectoer of 1s as constraints and zero as a result. I got coefficients including Intercept with sum=0 but they have nothing to do with those of R and therefore I can not use them to adjust my means, as averagetable would do in R.

Anybody any idea ? I can include code examples, but I think the query written as such is rather obvious... Getting lost, need friends.

Tx -)

Editing my question to answer Plato77: Tx for your interest Plato.

I work on a flie input named strawberries
I do a little bit of reshaping etc (maybe not the smartest way I am nothin but a Python expert)

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Aste\Desktop\PERSONNEL\Forms\Processing\Python\SelectedStrawberries.csv', sep=";", decimal =',')   #read the csv file (put 'r' before the path string to address any special characters in the path, such as '\'). Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + ".csv"


df=df.fillna(0)
df4=df.pivot_table(index=['Assessement date','Sample ID','Panelist','Replicate'], columns='Attributes', values='Score', aggfunc='first' )
df4.reset_index(inplace=True)

vec1=(df4[df4.columns[4]]) #condisering only first attribute in this test
vec2= (df4['Sample ID'])
vec3= (df4['Panelist'])
vec4= (df4['Replicate'])


df5=pd.DataFrame ({'Sample': vec2,'Panelist': vec3, 'Replicate': vec4,'score': vec1})
```

Now I ente rinto the tricky part which is to get models. If I use either ols or glm I get same coefficients

```
lm_glm1=ols('score ~ C(Sample) + C(Panelist) + C(Replicate)', data=df5).fit()
lm_glm2=glm('score ~ C(Sample) + C(Panelist) + C(Replicate)', data=df5).fit()
```

both methods give following coefficients for model, they do not sum to zero

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAAbf.png)

If I try to constraint the glm model (I did not find a way to constraint the ols one) as follows:

```
L=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
r=[0]

lm_glm=glm('score ~ C(Sample) + C(Panelist) + C(Replicate)', data=df5).fit_constrained((L, r))
```

I get coefficients that sum up to zero or close to, but they have nothing to do with what I get in R on same data with contrast contr.sum

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12dci.png)

My friend in R keeps telling me I should set contrast to contr.sum but no clue how to do this in Python...

Comment: Please can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hey Tx for looking, tried to explain things a little bit better rediting my post.